# Find occurrence count of the longest common Prefix/Suffix in a List of Strings?

Tags: java, string, algorithm, hashmap

Given a list of Strings:

```
ArrayList<String> strList = new ArrayList<String>();
strList.add("Mary had a little lamb named Willy");
strList.add("Mary had a little ham");
strList.add("Old McDonald had a farm named Willy");
strList.add("Willy had a little dog named ham");
strList.add("(abc)");
strList.add("(xyz)");
strList.add("Visit Target Store");
strList.add("Visit Walmart Store");
```

This should produce the output in the form of a `HashMap<String, Integer>` `prefixMap` and `suffixMap`:

**PREFIX**:

```
Mary had a -> 2
Mary had a little -> 2
( -> 2
Visit -> 2
```

**SUFFIX**:

```
named Willy -> 2
ham -> 2
) -> 2
Store -> 2
```

So far I'm able to generate a prefix that is present in all items in list using the following code:

```
public static final int INDEX_NOT_FOUND = -1;

public static String getAllCommonPrefixesInList(final String... strs) {
    if (strs == null || strs.length == 0) {
        return EMPTY_STRING;
    }
    
    
    final int smallestIndexOfDiff = getIndexOfDifference(strs);
    if (smallestIndexOfDiff == INDEX_NOT_FOUND) {
        
        // All Strings are identical
        if (strs[0] == null) {
            return EMPTY_STRING;
        }
        return strs[0];
    } else if (smallestIndexOfDiff == 0) {
        
        
        // No common initial characters found, return empty String
        return EMPTY_STRING;
    } else {
        
        // Common initial character sequence found, return sequence
        return strs[0].substring(0, smallestIndexOfDiff);
    }
}






public static int getIndexOfDifference(final CharSequence... charSequence) {
    if (charSequence == null || charSequence.length <= 1) {
        return INDEX_NOT_FOUND;
    }
    boolean isAnyStringNull = false;
    boolean areAllStringsNull = true;
    
    
    final int arrayLen = charSequence.length;
    int shortestStrLen = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int longestStrLen = 0;

    // Find the min and max string lengths - avoids having to check that we are not exceeding the length of the string each time through the bottom loop.
    for (int i = 0; i < arrayLen; i++) {
        if (charSequence[i] == null) {
            isAnyStringNull = true;
            shortestStrLen = 0;
        } else {
            areAllStringsNull = false;
            shortestStrLen = Math.min(charSequence[i].length(), shortestStrLen);
            longestStrLen = Math.max(charSequence[i].length(), longestStrLen);
        }
    }

    // Deals with lists containing all nulls or all empty strings
    
    if (areAllStringsNull || longestStrLen == 0 && !isAnyStringNull) {
        return INDEX_NOT_FOUND;
    }

    // Handle lists containing some nulls or some empty strings
    if (shortestStrLen == 0) {
        return 0;
    }

    // Find the position with the first difference across all strings
    int firstDiff = -1;
    for (int stringPos = 0; stringPos < shortestStrLen; stringPos++) {
        final char comparisonChar = charSequence[0].charAt(stringPos);
        for (int arrayPos = 1; arrayPos < arrayLen; arrayPos++) {
            if (charSequence[arrayPos].charAt(stringPos) != comparisonChar) {
                firstDiff = stringPos;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (firstDiff != -1) {
            break;
        }
    }

    if (firstDiff == -1 && shortestStrLen != longestStrLen) {
        
        // We compared all of the characters up to the length of the
        // shortest string and didn't find a match, but the string lengths
        // vary, so return the length of the shortest string.
        return shortestStrLen;
    }
    return firstDiff;
}
```

However, my goal is to include any ***prefix***/***suffix*** with at least **`2+`** occurrences into the resulting map.

How can this be achieved with `Java`?

Comment: I think the expected result should be, is it correct?
Mary -> 2
Mary had -> 2
Mary had a -> 2
Mary had a little -> 2
( -> 2
Visit -> 2

SUFFIX:
Willy -> 2
named Willy -> 2
ham -> 2
) -> 2
Store -> 2

Comment: @Thinhbk the output would also include strings like `Mar`, `Visi` etc since they're also valid prefixes

Comment: Can you include the full output of the prefix and suffix maps, if the current output is only a sample? The fact that ‘(‘ is a prefix implies you want all prefixes, but your examples mostly include prefixes ending at word boundaries

Comment: At first I thought each node of a trie will hold the word for this case, if each node of the trie holds a character then the output should be much larger. My algo below make this assumption, so the output only catch the word, not all the prefix.

Comment: Seems like a job for a [suffix tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree#:~:text=In%20computer%20science%2C%20a%20suffix,of%20many%20important%20string%20operations.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my understanding of this problem the most suitable data structure for solving it is an acyclic disjointed **Graph**.

In general case, a **graph** will be comprised of several unconnected ***clusters***. Each *cluster* will have a *tree-like* structure, in the edge case it'll form a *linked list*.

Basically, the most simple *naive* approach on how to solve this problem is to create a bunch of *linked list* based on each line, and iterate over them. The drawbacks are: *duplication of nodes* (greater memory consumption), greater *time-complexity* (more operations required) and it's more *error-prone* because more manual actions are needed.

#### The description of the Graph

So I'll stick with the **graph** as the data structure for this problem and try to keep things as simple as possible.

Let's consider the following input:

```
"Mary had a little lamb named Willy"
"Mary had a little ham"
"A B C"
```

The graphical representation of the graph will look like this;

[image]

The two first lines will constitute a *cluster* formed from a *linked list* (the head part) and a *tree* (the tail part). The second cluster will be represented by a *linked list*, its vertices aren't connected with vertices formed from other strings.

It's not the only way the vertexes can be structured, the head could spawn an *N-tree* and a linked list could be observed somewhere in the middle.

The main takeaway is that in order to solve the problem, we need to track the chain of vertexes through all the branches until the **vertexes overlap**. In these parts of the *graph*, every prefix-strings and suffix-string that is common among two or more lines will be represented by a **single vertex** (*node*).

To maintain the number of strings that are mapped to a particular *vertex*, each vertex should have a variable (`int groupCount` *in the code below*), which is assigned with a default value of `1` when a *vertex* is being created and incremented each time a new string gets mapped to this vertex.

Each *vertex* contains a map that holds references to its *neighbours*. When a new *neighbour-vertex* is being added, either new `Vertex` in being created based on the given string or the *count* of an existing *vertex* gets incremented.

In order to conform to this task, *the graph* should maintain references to all *head-vertexes* and *tail-vertexes*. For simplicity, instead of maintaining two groups of references to adjacent nodes, and two separate count variables (*because suffix-count and prefix-count will differ*) in each vertex, in this solution *graph* is actually comprised of **two graph** (*suffix-graph* and *prefix-graph*). And for that reason, the implementing class in named `MultiGraph`.

In order to populate both *suffix-graph* and *prefix-graph* with *vertexes*, method `addCluster()` iterates over the string of the given line by the means of `Iterator` in normal or reversed order, depending on which *graph* is being populated.

#### Depth first search

The next step after the graphs are populated is to generate the maps of strings with the frequency of `2` and greater.

For that, the classical [**depth first search**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) algorithm is being used.

In order to implement the DFS, a mutable container that will be used as a **stack** is required (`ArrayDeque` is being used for that purpose). The first element that is taken from the *map of heads/tails* will be placed on the top of the *stack* and an instance of `StringBuilder` holding the name of this element will be placed in the map.

Then, to restore a string with a particular *count*, *vertexes* will be popped from the top of the *stack* and their *neighbours* with count `> 1` in turn will be placed on top of the stack. A copy of the *current prefix* with the delimiter and the neighbour's name appended will get mapped to the *neighbour-vertex*.

If a *count* changes, that indicates that the *current prefix* represents the longest common string between at least two lines. In this case, prefix and count are being added to the resulting map.

#### Implementation

The following implementation consists of two classes that are *narrow-focused* and *self-contained*. The `MultiGraph` class acts exclusively as data structure, maintaining two graphs. The pluming code, like splitting the lines of strings, is extracted into a separate class `GraphManager`.

**Graph**

```java
public class MultiGraph {
    private final Map<String, Vertex> heads = new HashMap<>();
    private final Map<String, Vertex> tails = new HashMap<>();

    public void addCluster(Deque<String> names) {
        addCluster(heads, names.iterator());
        addCluster(tails, names.descendingIterator());
    }

    private void addCluster(Map<String, Vertex> clusters, Iterator<String> names) {
        String rootName = names.next();
        if (clusters.containsKey(rootName)) {
            clusters.get(rootName).incrementGroupCount();
        } else {
            clusters.put(rootName, new Vertex(rootName));
        }

        Vertex current = clusters.get(rootName);
        while (names.hasNext()) {
            current = current.addNext(names.next());
        }
    }

    public Map<String, Integer> generatePrefixMap(String delimiter) {
        Map<String, Integer> countByPrefix = new HashMap<>();

        for (Vertex next: heads.values()) {
            if (next.getGroupCount() == 1) {
                continue;
            }
            performDFS(heads, countByPrefix, delimiter, next);
        }
        return countByPrefix;
    }

    public Map<String, Integer> generateSuffixMap(String delimiter) {
        Map<String, Integer> countBySuffix = new HashMap<>();

        for (Vertex next: tails.values()) {
            if (next.getGroupCount() == 1) {
                continue;
            }
            performDFS(tails, countBySuffix, delimiter, next);
        }
        return countBySuffix;
    }
    // implementation of the Depth First Search algorithm
    public void performDFS(Map<String, Vertex> clusters,
                           Map<String, Integer> countByPrefix,
                           String delimiter, Vertex next) {

        StringBuilder prefix = null;
        Vertex current = next;
        int count = next.getGroupCount();

        Deque<Vertex> stack = new ArrayDeque<>(); // create as stack
        Map<Vertex, StringBuilder> prefixByVert = new HashMap<>();
        stack.push(next); // place the first element on the stack
        prefixByVert.put(current, new StringBuilder(current.getName()));

        while (!stack.isEmpty()) {
            current = stack.pop();
            if (current.getGroupCount() < count) { // the number of strings mapped to the current Vertex has been changed
                countByPrefix.put(prefix.toString(), count); // saving the result
                count = current.getGroupCount();
            }
            prefix = prefixByVert.get(current);

            for (Vertex neighbour: current.getNextVertByVal().values()) {
                if (next.getGroupCount() == 1) {
                    continue;
                }
                stack.push(neighbour);
                prefixByVert.put(neighbour, new StringBuilder(prefix)
                                    .append(delimiter)
                                    .append(neighbour.getName()));
            }
        }

        if (prefix != null && count > 1) {
            countByPrefix.putIfAbsent(prefix.toString(), count);
        }
    }

    private static class Vertex {
        private final String name;
        private int groupCount = 1;
        private final Map<String, Vertex> nextVertByVal = new HashMap<>();

        public Vertex(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public Vertex addNext(String value) {
            if (nextVertByVal.containsKey(value)) {
                nextVertByVal.get(value).incrementGroupCount();
            } else {
                nextVertByVal.put(value, new Vertex(value));
            }
            return nextVertByVal.get(value);
        }

        public void incrementGroupCount() {
            this.groupCount++;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public int getGroupCount() {
            return groupCount;
        }

        public Map<String, Vertex> getNextVertByVal() {
            return nextVertByVal;
        }
    }
}
```

The following class deals with the task of processing the input data: it splits the lines, takes care of discarding the empty string which might take place, and packs the input into a `Deque` to accommodate the iteration in both directions in a convenient way.

It also instantiates the *graph* and governs it's work. `GraphManager` takes care of providing the *delimiter* to the graph in order to restore the initial shape of strings while the resulting maps are being created. With that you can split the given lines on a white space, by empty string to process lines character by character or by punctuation marks without changing a single line in these two classes.

**GraphManager**

```java
public class GraphManager {
    private MultiGraph graph = new MultiGraph();
    private String delimiter;

    private GraphManager(String delimiter) {
        this.delimiter = delimiter;
    }

    public static GraphManager getInstance(Iterable<String> lines, String delimiter) {
        GraphManager gm = new GraphManager(delimiter);
        gm.init(lines);
        return gm;
    }

    private void init(Iterable<String> lines) {
        for (String line: lines) {
            Deque<String> names = new ArrayDeque<>();
            for (String name: line.split(delimiter)) {
                if (!name.isEmpty()) {
                    names.add(name);
                }
            }
            addCluster(names);
        }
    }

    private void addCluster(Deque<String> names) {
        graph.addCluster(names);
    }

    public Map<String, Integer> getPrefixMap() {
        return graph.generatePrefixMap(delimiter);
    }

    public Map<String, Integer> getSuffixMap() {
        return graph.generateSuffixMap(delimiter);
    }
}
```

**main()**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> lines = List.of(
            "Mary had a little lamb named Willy", "Mary had a little ham",
            "Old McDonald had a farm named Willy", "Willy had a little dog named ham",
            "( abc )", "( xyz )", "Visit Target Store", "Visit Walmart Store");

    GraphManager gm = GraphManager.getInstance(lines, " ");
    
    System.out.println("Prefixes:");
    for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry: gm.getPrefixMap().entrySet()) {
        System.out.println(entry.getValue() + " " + entry.getKey());
    }

    System.out.println("\nSuffixes:");
    for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry: gm.getSuffixMap().entrySet()) {
        System.out.println(entry.getValue() + " " + entry.getKey());
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
Prefixes:
2 Mary had a little
2 Visit
2 (

Suffixes:
2 ham
2 )
2 Store
2 Willy named
```

Comment: If the "clusters" have a common root node, you'll get a tree

Comment: @AbhinavMathur What do you mean by "common root"? A *cluster* by definition is a part of a graph that is **separate** from other parts. Does the all strings in OP's example have a "common root" or they are disjointed? Tree is an edge case when you have all strings starting with the same word.

Comment: All strings have the empty string ("") as a common prefix

Comment: @AbhinavMathur Is there an empty string in the PO's example? It should have a count of `8` for both prefixes and suffixes, and therefore must be listed. That is an artificial argument.

Comment: @AbhinavMathur Quote from the question: *my goal is include **any prefix/suffix** with at least **2+ occurrences** in the final map and include the number of occurrences in the map*

Comment: My point is, having a common root for an empty string, it's easy to see why a trie would be useful

Comment: @AbhinavMathur You ignored my question, we are discussing a particular task. And did you utilize somehow the empty string node in your solution?

Comment: Abhinav is technically correct, although this seems to just be a disagreement over vague definitions in the original post. OP’s example mostly shows prefixes composed of whole words, while their code generates all prefixes, including those ending in the middle of a word. The trie data structure, for convenience, often includes the empty string as a common root. By definition, the empty string is a prefix of all strings. Also, minor correction, the word ‘cluster’ has no very common meaning in graph theory: the word you’re describing is usually called ‘component’

Comment: @kcsquared OP didn't provide the runnable code. But we have a clear requirement: "**any prefix/suffix with at least 2+ occurrences**", there has to an empty string with a count of `8` in the example, but there isn't. Can you point at any solution listed here that utilizes somehow a node with the empty string?

Comment: Unfortunately, OP’s example is incomplete, and they didn’t clearly define the terms prefix and suffix. Their example, if it were complete, should also have the prefix “Mary had”, right? So, using the most common definition of “prefix” in computer science, a prefix doesn’t have to end at a space or delimiter. By definition, the empty string is a prefix of all strings, just like the empty set is a subset of all sets. Only OP can probably clear up the miscommunication, and specify “Nonempty prefixes ending at word boundaries/ delimiters” if that is what they meant.

Comment: @kcsquared That's a practical task, let's OP say their word. And I also don't see any evidence of the usage of empty string among the solutions listed here. I mean, I didn't spot any code in these 4 answers which deliberately produces a node with an empty string as a value.

Comment: If I may chime in and give my two cents.... As a matter of practice, it is my opinion that the best approach to the argument of "_having a common root for an empty string_" is not to include it unless a specific requirement indicates so. Since the OP has not made this point clear, Alexander's point of having a clear (specific) requirement should be the main point of focus. This is how real-world applications are build for the most part. Often, it is better to include new behaviors than remove them later on.

Comment: This answer is nicely illustrated, the decision for the taken approach is clearly articulated in great detail, and the provided implementation is also explained nicely. I do agree with kcsquared that OP left out many details. I also agree that an empty set is a subset of all sets. However, this is only true because it is mathematically defined this way. In my opinion, it might be a bit of a stretch to make the assertion that an empty string is a valid prefix for all strings.

Comment: @hfontanez Agreed. This answer is clearly very high quality, and the decision about what exactly to count as a prefix is minor and can be modified without changing the underlying algorithm. My only real issue with this answer is the first sentence, since I also think Abhinav's approach is correct, and a good example of using a Trie.

Answer (score 4):

This problem should be solved easily using a [trie](https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/data-structures/advanced-data-structures/trie-keyword-tree/tutorial/).

The trie node should basically keep a track of 2 things:

1. Child nodes
2. Count of prefixes ending at current node

Insert all strings in the trie, which will be done in `O(string length * number of strings)`. After that, simply traversing the trie, you can hash the prefixes based on the count as per your use case. For suffixes, you can use the same approach, just start traversing the strings in reverse order.

Edit:
On second thought, trie might be the most efficient way, but a simple hashmap implementation should also work here. Here's an example to generate all prefixes with count > 1.

```java
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.*;

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    System.out.println("Hello world!");

    ArrayList<String> strList = new ArrayList<String>();
    
    strList.add("Mary had a little lamb named Willy");
    strList.add("Mary had a little ham");
    strList.add("Old McDonald had a farm named Willy");
    strList.add("Willy had a little dog named ham");
    strList.add("(abc)");
    strList.add("(xyz)");
    strList.add("Visit Target Store");
    strList.add("Visit Walmart Store");

    Map<String, Integer> prefixMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    ArrayList<String> stringsWithHighestOccurrence = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (String word : strList) {
            for (int i = 1; i <= word.length(); i++){
        String prefix = word.substring(0, i);
        prefixMap.merge(prefix, 1, Integer::sum);
      }
        }

    Integer maxval = Collections.max(prefixMap.values());

    for (String key: prefixMap.keySet()){
      Integer value = prefixMap.get(key);
      if (value > 1) System.out.println(key + " : " + value);
      if (value == maxval) stringsWithHighestOccurrence.add(key);
    }

    int maxLength = stringsWithHighestOccurrence.stream().map(String::length).max(Integer::compareTo).get();
    
    System.out.println(maxLength);

    ArrayList<String> prefixesWithMaxLength =
stringsWithHighestOccurrence.stream().filter(c -> c.length() == maxLength).collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
    System.out.println(prefixesWithMaxLength);
  }
}
```

Nonetheless, I'll also add a basic `TrieNode` implementation for the sake of completion, since my answer proposed that approach in the first place.

`TrieNode`:

```java
class TrieNode {
    private final Map<Character, TrieNode> children = new HashMap<>();
    private int count;

    Map<Character, TrieNode> getChildren() {
        return children;
    }

    boolean getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    void increaseCount() {
        this.count += 1;
    }
}
```

`Trie`:

```java
class Trie {
    private TrieNode root;

    Trie() {
        root = new TrieNode();
    }

    void insert(String word) {
        TrieNode current = root;

        for (char l : word.toCharArray()) {
            current = current.getChildren().computeIfAbsent(l, c -> new TrieNode());
            current.increaseCount()
        }
    }
}
```

Traversing the trie would be analogous to a simple DFS scenario where the "path" upto current node is also maintained (we're switching the path with the prefix upto this point).

Comment: Do you mind adding some Java code to illustrate how this concept might be implemented? Thanks!

Comment: @AgustinNetto added a basic implementation

Comment: @AbhinavMathur Thanks for your response. I tried extending the code but could not get it to produce the desired output. If you are able to extend the code so that it takes the list of Strings in OP and produces `prefixMap` + `suffixMap` with count I would open a +50 bounty once the question is eligible for one and award it. Thanks!

Comment: @LeviHibbitts can you add your modified approach (with inputs etc set up) on something like replit.com?

Comment: @AbhinavMathur I'm having a little trouble getting it to compile on replit.com but here's a link to all the code: https://replit.com/@aix3/LongestPrefix#Main.java (it compiles locally fine). Hopefully, you can provide some feedback. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

To implement a [trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie), first you need a node.

```
class Node<T> {

    private final T value;
    private final Node<T> parent;
    private final Map<T, Node<T>> children;
    private boolean isEnd;

    Node(T value, Node<T> parent) {
        this.value = value;
        this.parent = parent;
        this.children = new HashMap<>();
        this.isEnd = false;
    }

    Node<T> addChild(T childValue, Node<T> parent) {
        //return child node if existing, otherwise create and return
       return this.children.computeIfAbsent(childValue, value -> new Node<>(value, parent));
    }

    T getValue() {
        return this.value;
    }

    Node<T> getParent() {
        return this.parent;
    }

    boolean isEnd() {
        return this.isEnd;
    }

    void setEnd(boolean isEnd) {
        this.isEnd = isEnd;
    }

    Collection<Node<T>> children() {
        return this.children.values();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        //for easier debugging
        return "Node{" +
                "value=" + this.value +
                ", children=" + this.children.keySet() +
                ", isEnd=" + this.isEnd +
                '}';
    }
}
```

In the node we have actual value, reference to the parent node, to make it eaiser to build prefixes, child nodes mapped value to corresponding node, and a flag if node is end node.

Actual `Trie` implementation

```
public class Trie<T> {

    private final Node<T> root;

    public Trie() {
        this.root = new Node<>(null, null);
    }

    public void insert(T[] elements) {
        if (elements.length == 0) {
            //don't want to set root as end node
            return;
        }
        Node<T> currentNode = this.root;
        for (T element : elements) {
            currentNode = currentNode.addChild(element, currentNode);
        }
        currentNode.setEnd(true);
    }

    public Map<Collection<T>, Integer> countPrefixes(BiConsumer<Deque<T>, T> operation) {
        Map<Collection<T>, Integer> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        this.countPrefixes(this.root, map, operation);
        return map;
    }

    private void countPrefixes(Node<T> current, Map<Collection<T>, Integer> map, BiConsumer<Deque<T>, T> operation) {
        if (current != this.root) {
            //check java doc for AbstractSet hashCode and equals
            ArrayList<T> prefix = this.buildKey(current, operation);
            int childrenCount = current.children().size();
            if (childrenCount == 0 && current.isEnd()) {
                //this sets entire collection(entire sentence 'Mary had a little lamb named Willy' for example)
                //as prefix which is met once
                childrenCount = 1;
            }
            map.merge(prefix, childrenCount, Integer::sum);
            if (childrenCount > 1) {
                //each parent node is already marked as prefix met once,
                //but any node having more than one child means entire chain of nodes
                //is a prefix met the number of children,
                //so we go backwards to update parent counts with the difference
                this.updateParentPrefixes(current.getParent(), childrenCount - 1, map, operation);
            }
        }
        for (Node<T> child : current.children()) {
            //visit each child recursively to count them
            //depth first
            this.countPrefixes(child, map, operation);
        }
    }

    //operation is abstraction for the order
    //in which we want to add elements
    //when building key/prefix
    private ArrayList<T> buildKey(Node<T> node, BiConsumer<Deque<T>, T> operation) {
        Deque<T> prefix = new LinkedList<>();
        while (node.getValue() != null) {
            operation.accept(prefix, node.getValue());
            node = node.getParent();
        }
        return new ArrayList<>(prefix);
    }

    private void updateParentPrefixes(Node<T> parent, int updateCount, Map<Collection<T>, Integer> map, BiConsumer<Deque<T>, T> operation) {
        if (parent == this.root) {
            //we don't want to update root, ever!!!
            return;
        }
        ArrayList<T> prefix = this.buildKey(parent, operation);
        map.merge(prefix, updateCount, Integer::sum);
        //visit parents recursively until root
        this.updateParentPrefixes(parent.getParent(), updateCount, map, operation);
    }
}
```

It is somewhat simplified in the sense, that only `insert` is implemented, but we don't need update and delete now. Few things to note:

1. Trie must have a **root** node, which is empty. We are representing that with `null` value and `null` parent. We must **never** update this node.
2. Parameter `BiConsumer<Deque<T>, T> operation` of `countPrefixes()`. This is abstraction for the order in which we want to add elements when creating a prefix. It's needed, because counting suffixes can be represented, and is implemented, as counting prefixes when reversing the collection/sentence.
3. Return type `Map<Collection<T>, Integer>` of `countPrefixes()`. This implementation is more generic, thus each prefix is represented as **collection of node values**.
4. Why prefix is `ArrayList`? First we need to keep insertion order. Second its' implementation of `hashCode()` and `equals()` makes it good candidate for map key. To citate [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html):

`This ensures that list1.equals(list2) implies that list1.hashCode()==list2.hashCode() for any two lists, list1 and list2, as required by the general contract of Object.hashCode.` - for hashCode.

`In other words, two lists are defined to be equal if they contain the same elements in the same order.` - for equals.

5. The comments in code should explain the rest of the specifics in implementation.

A main to test.

```
public class TrieMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String spacePattern = "\\s+";
        String emptyStringPattern = "";

        ArrayList<String> strList = new ArrayList<>();
        strList.add("Mary had a little lamb named Willy");
        strList.add("Mary had a little ham");
        strList.add("Mary had a sandwich");
        strList.add("Old McDonald had a farm named Willy");
        strList.add("Willy had a little dog named ham");
        strList.add("Willy had a big dog named Willy");
        strList.add("Willy had a huge dog named Willy");
        strList.add("(abc)");
        strList.add("(xyz)");
        strList.add("Visit Target Store");
        strList.add("Visit Walmart Store");

        Trie<String> trie = new Trie<>();
        //using another trie for suffix to avoid counting suffix as prefix and vice versa
        Trie<String> reversedTrie = new Trie<>();
        for (String string : strList) {
            String pattern = string.startsWith("(") ? emptyStringPattern : spacePattern;
            String[] words = string.split(pattern);
            trie.insert(words);

            //reverse collection to count suffixes
            Collections.reverse(Arrays.asList(words));
            reversedTrie.insert(words);
        }
        Map<Collection<String>, Integer> prefixCount = trie.countPrefixes(Deque::addFirst);
        System.out.println("Prefixes:");
        printMap(prefixCount);
        System.out.println();
        Map<Collection<String>, Integer> suffixCount = reversedTrie.countPrefixes(Deque::addLast);
        System.out.println("Suffixes:");
        printMap(suffixCount);
    }

    private static void printMap(Map<Collection<String>, Integer> map) {
        map.entrySet()
                .stream()
                .filter(entry -> entry.getValue() > 1)
                .forEach(e -> {
                    String key = String.join(" ", e.getKey());
                    String line = String.format("%s -> %d", key, e.getValue());
                    System.out.println(line);
                });
    }
}
```

Things to note here:

1. Added few more sentences in the list for extra testing.
2. I am splitting the inputs with `(` into characters and not words as the rest to achieve your output, but example is somewhat confusing. For sentences prefixes are collection of words, while for those two they are characters.
3. Need second `trie` for suffixes - otherwise we might count prefix as suffix and vice versa.
4. `Arrays.asList()` returned list is backed by input array. I am taking advantage of that to reverse the input array itself for suffixes.

**EDIT:** While testing with characters realized [AbstractSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/AbstractSet.html), or any set to be precise, is a bad idea for prefix, because it does not allow duplicated elements. Updated trie implementation to use `ArrayList`. I'm also adding 2 more main methods, to demonstrate the trie working with strings and with characters:

1. **Strings** - each node is a word, acquired by splitting strings by space

```
public class TrieWords {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String> strList = new ArrayList<>();
        strList.add("Mary had a little lamb named Willy");
        strList.add("Mary had a little ham");
        strList.add("Mary had a sandwich");
        strList.add("Old McDonald had a farm named Willy");
        strList.add("Willy had a little dog named ham");
        strList.add("Willy had a big dog named Willy");
        strList.add("Willy had a huge dog named Willy");
        strList.add("(abc)");
        strList.add("(xyz)");
        strList.add("Visit Target Store");
        strList.add("Visit Walmart Store");

        Trie<String> trie = new Trie<>();
        //using another trie for suffix to avoid counting suffix as prefix and vice versa
        Trie<String> reversedTrie = new Trie<>();
        for (String string : strList) {
            String[] words = string.split("\\s+");
            trie.insert(words);

            //reverse collection to count suffixes
            Collections.reverse(Arrays.asList(words));
            reversedTrie.insert(words);
        }
        Map<Collection<String>, Integer> prefixCount = trie.countPrefixes(Deque::addFirst);
        System.out.println("Prefixes:");
        printMap(prefixCount);
        System.out.println();
        Map<Collection<String>, Integer> suffixCount = reversedTrie.countPrefixes(Deque::addLast);
        System.out.println("Suffixes:");
        printMap(suffixCount);
    }

    private static void printMap(Map<Collection<String>, Integer> map) {
        map.entrySet()
                .stream()
                .filter(entry -> entry.getValue() > 1)
                .forEach(e -> {
                    String key = String.join(" ", e.getKey());
                    String line = String.format("%s -> %d", key, e.getValue());
                    System.out.println(line);
                });
    }
}
```

2. **Characters** - each node is a character from the string

```
public class TrieChars {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String> strList = new ArrayList<>();
        strList.add("Mary had a little lamb named Willy");
        strList.add("Mary had a little ham");
        strList.add("Mary had a sandwich");
        strList.add("Old McDonald had a farm named Willy");
        strList.add("Willy had a little dog named ham");
        strList.add("Willy had a big dog named Willy");
        strList.add("Willy had a huge dog named Willy");
        strList.add("(abcd)");
        strList.add("(xyz)");
        strList.add("Visit Target Store");
        strList.add("Visit Walmart Store");

        Trie<Character> trie = new Trie<>();
        //using another trie for suffix to avoid counting suffix as prefix and vice versa
        Trie<Character> reversedTrie = new Trie<>();
        for (String string : strList) {
            int length = string.length();
            Character[] words = new Character[length];
            Character[] reversed = new Character[length];
            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                int reversedIndex = length - 1 - i;
                words[i] = string.charAt(i);
                reversed[reversedIndex] = string.charAt(i);
            }
            trie.insert(words);
            reversedTrie.insert(reversed);
        }
        Map<Collection<Character>, Integer> prefixCount = trie.countPrefixes(Deque::addFirst);
        System.out.println("Prefixes:");
        printMap(prefixCount);
        System.out.println();
        Map<Collection<Character>, Integer> suffixCount = reversedTrie.countPrefixes(Deque::addLast);
        System.out.println("Suffixes:");
        printMap(suffixCount);
    }

    private static void printMap(Map<Collection<Character>, Integer> map) {
        map.entrySet()
                .stream()
                .filter(entry -> entry.getValue() > 1)
                .forEach(e -> {
                    String key = e.getKey().stream().map(Object::toString).collect(Collectors.joining(""));
                    String line = String.format("%s -> %d", key, e.getValue());
                    System.out.println(line);
                });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution provided by @Abhinav should work using HashMap. Here I will post the solution using a simple Trie implementation in java (with some customization, such as adding freq into the Trie Node).

```
    ArrayList<String> strList = new ArrayList<String>();
    strList.add("Mary had a little lamb named Willy");
    strList.add("Mary had a little ham");
    strList.add("Old McDonald had a farm named Willy");
    strList.add("Willy had a little dog named ham");
    strList.add("( abc )");
    strList.add("( xyz )");
    strList.add("Visit Target Store");
    strList.add("Visit Walmart Store");

    TNode root = new TNode("");
    int maxFreq = 1;
    for(String sentence : strList) {
        TNode currentNode = root;
        String[] words = sentence.split(" "); // Assuming space character is the delimiter 
        for(String word: words) {
            if(currentNode.children.containsKey(word)) {
                currentNode.children.get(word).freq += 1;
                maxFreq = Math.max(maxFreq, currentNode.children.get(word).freq);
            } else {
                TNode c = new TNode(word);
                c.freq = 1;
                currentNode.children.put(word, c);
            }
            currentNode = currentNode.children.get(word);
        }
    }

    Map<String, Integer> result = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    Queue<NodeWithPrefix> queue = new LinkedList<NodeWithPrefix>();
    for(TNode node : root.children.values()){
        NodeWithPrefix nwp = new NodeWithPrefix(node);
        nwp.prefix = "";
        queue.add(nwp);
    }
    while(!queue.isEmpty()) {
        NodeWithPrefix item = queue.poll();
        if(item.node.freq == maxFreq) {
            result.put(item.prefix + " " + item.node.value, item.node.freq);
        }
        for(TNode child : item.node.children.values()) {
            NodeWithPrefix nwp = new NodeWithPrefix(child);
            nwp.prefix = item.prefix + " " + item.node.value;
            queue.add(nwp);
        }
    }
    return result;
```

Here are 2 other classes required for this algorithm:

```
class NodeWithPrefix {
    String prefix;
    TNode node;
    public NodeWithPrefix(TNode node){
        this.node = node;
    }
}

class TNode {
    String value;
    int freq = 0;
    Map<String, TNode> children;
    public TNode(String value){
        this.value = value;
        children = new HashMap<String, TNode>();
    }
}
```

The output is for prefix: (for postfix should be similar, just need to build the Trie backward)

```
{ Mary had=2,  Mary had a=2,  Visit=2,  (=2,  Mary had a little=2,  Mary=2}
```

Here I am using a BFS to retrieve all sub strings having frequency equal maxFreq in the Trie. We can adjust the filter condition based on the need. You can do the DFS here also.
Other consideration is we can add prefix into the TNode class itself, I prefer to keep it separate in another class.

Comment: My algorithm is assuming the output only containing words (based on the sample output), so each Trie Node is customized to hold a word. Originally each Node of the Trie will hold a character, then in that case the output of the prefix should be much larger.