# Extract the Longest Common String with the same Occurrence Count from a Map in Java?

Tags: java, algorithm, filter, hashmap

I have a `Map<String, Integer>` mapping a String with the number of occurrences of each String in map:

```
String: Vis Count: 2
String: Visi Count: 2
String: Visit Count: 2
String: Vi Count: 2
String: V Count: 2
String: Visit  Count: 2
String: Visit Walmart St Count: 1
String: Visit Target S Count: 1
String: Visit Target St Count: 1
String: Visit Walmart Sto Count: 1
String: Visit Walma Count: 1
String: Visit T Count: 1
String: Visit Walmart Store Count: 1
String: Visit Target Sto Count: 1
String: Visit Target Stor Count: 1
String: Visit Walmart S Count: 1
String: Visit Targe Count: 1
String: Visit Target Store Count: 1
String: Visit W Count: 1
String: Visit Walmar Count: 1
String: Visit Wal Count: 1
String: Visit Walmart Count: 1
String: Visit Ta Count: 1
String: Visit Walmart Stor Count: 1
String: Visit Walm Count: 1
String: Visit Wa Count: 1
String: Visit Tar Count: 1
String: Visit Target  Count: 1
String: Visit Walmart  Count: 1
String: Visit Targ Count: 1
String: Visit Target Count: 1
```

---

The above map was generated using the following code:

```
ArrayList<String> strList = new ArrayList<String>();
strList.add("Visit Target Store");
strList.add("Visit Walmart Store");


HashMap<String, Integer> strPositionMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
HashSet<String> set = new HashSet<String>();



for (String strFromList : strList) {
        

    for (int charArrCounter = 0; charArrCounter < strFromList.length(); charArrCounter++) {
        
        
        int lastIndex = charArrCounter + 1;
        
        String strBuilderFromCharArr = strFromList.substring(0, lastIndex);
        
        System.out.println("Counter: " + charArrCounter + " String: " + strBuilderFromCharArr + " Char Count: " + strBuilderFromCharArr.length());
        
        if (set.contains(strBuilderFromCharArr)) {
            System.out.println("Skipping String: " + strBuilderFromCharArr + " because it's already in set -> " + set.toString());
            continue;
        } else {
            
            set.add(strBuilderFromCharArr);
        }
        
        
        
        for (String stFromrList : strList) {                
            

            if (stFromrList.startsWith(strBuilderFromCharArr)) {
                

                System.out.println("String from list: " + stFromrList + " starts with: " + strBuilderFromCharArr);
                
                int count = strPositionMap.containsKey(strBuilderFromCharArr) ? strPositionMap.get(strBuilderFromCharArr) : 0;
                strPositionMap.put(strBuilderFromCharArr, count + 1);
                
            } else {
                
                System.out.println("String from list: " + stFromrList + " does NOT start with: " + strBuilderFromCharArr);

            }
        }               
    }       
}

// Sorts map by value from highest to lowest
Map<String, Integer> newStrPositionMap = HashMapUtil.sortByComparator(strPositionMap, false);


for (Entry<String, Integer> newStrPositionMapEntrySet : newStrPositionMap.entrySet()) {
                
    System.out.println("String: " + newStrPositionMapEntrySet.getKey() + " Count: " + newStrPositionMapEntrySet.getValue());
    
}
```

I now need to filter the above map so that a new map only includes one instance of two or more *similar* Strings with the same number of occurrences. In this context similar means that the two Strings start with the same char sequence and begin to fork at a certain point.

For example, the following Strings are all considered equivalent:

```
String: V Count: 2
String: Vi Count: 2
String: Vis Count: 2
String: Visi Count: 2
String: Visit Count: 2
String: Visit  Count: 2
```

So the only String that should be preserved in the new map from the above list would be: `String: Visit  Count: 2` as all of the other Strings **1)** have the same count as this String **2)** are present in the "longest" String.

I'm using **Java**.

Thanks

**UPDATE 1**:

As @Phenomenal One requested..

Expected output for Prefix Map would be `Map<String, Integer>` with the following values:

```
Key: Visit Value: 2
```

Expected output for Suffix Map would be `Map<String, Integer>` with the following values:

```
Key: t Store Value: 2
```

Comment: Can you share what is the expected output for the above input map that you have shared

Comment: What metric are you using to determine similarity?

Comment: @PhenomenalOne I added the expected output to OP.

Comment: @AbhinavMathur Similarity is determined when two Strings start with the same sequence of chars when comparing prefix and when two Strings end with the same chars when generating suffix. For example, for prefix, the word `visit` would be similar to `v, vi, vis, visi` as it starts with these chars.. it would NOT be similar to `sit` even though it contains "sit" at the end (as we are analyzing prefix, different story when analyzing suffix). Hope this helps clarify things.. Thanks!

Comment: @AbhinavMathur No (why do you think so? It must be sequential.. if this is what you mean to ask)  BTW, I [just started a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71463016/find-occurrence-count-of-longest-common-prefix-suffix-in-list-of-strings) on my other question which you replied to (happy to award it to you if your interested in the challenge)

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are asking here is straightforward. You need to implement a Trie.

You need to initialize a TrieNode like the one below

```
class TrieNode {
    private HashMap<Character, TrieNode> children;
    private long count;
    private boolean isEnd;
    
   // ...
}
```

Insert values to this TrieNode and store the count of it when you meet the end.

So, going by your example:

V(2) -> i (2) -> s(2) -> i(2) -> t(2).

Now, simply iterate the root TrieNode  by the getting its count. When the count next count does not match with the previous count, you can stop there and return the computed characters with the count.

For suffix map, do the same thing , but store the TrieNode in reverse.